# How to redefine a keyboard shortcut PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Help me out, colleagues.

Switching from Sublime Text to PhpStorm opened up a lot of possibilities for me, but I was constantly using the search function for files inside the project (<kbd>CTRL + P</kbd>). In PhpStorm, there is an analog in the form of a double Shift and <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + N</kbd> (which is this <kbd>CTRL + P</kbd>).

Double-clicking Shift gives a lot of garbage (in my opinion), but the command <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + N</kbd> is just what I need. Is it possible to somehow redefine the keyboard shortcut to the good old <kbd>CTRL + P</kbd> as in Sublime Text?

Comment: Have you tried [adding a new keyboard short cut](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html#add-keyboard-shortcut) for it? Not sure if that works for you or not (not using PHPStorm myself)

Comment: It is - go to preferences and change `Keymap`. However... instead of using shortcuts from other soft (nobody said they are good although they're old...) IMHO it's better to learn new one. Keep in mind that PhpStorm is part of JetBrains' ecosystem and learning shortcuts in one product you'll know them in others. Do you want (in future) edit them everytime when installing any other IDE from JB? Also looking for help on forums you'll need to explain alway why you use `CTRL+P` instead of common shortcut known in PS

Comment: P.s. I dunno what's shortcut for Win version of PS, however there's dialog box `Edit > Find > Find in path` which allows you to search files by its contents with different contexts and sources with many good options. Usually good enough to search really large projects.

Comment: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html#choose-keymap 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html#add-keyboard-shortcut 3) There **might be** a Sublime-alike keymap (can be installed as an Ordinary plugin). But I recommend getting used to the standard one ... as very often you will see other people mentioning those shortcuts .. so it will avoid a confusion for you. It will take a bit of time, but it's better overall.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank your for your advice and response! Yes, I think it's a good idea to get used to it, but I'm probably not ready to do it yet, it's just that on my laptop, the keyboard shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+N is quite inconvenent. THank you again for your answer!